# How can I get WinRT InputScope to work in C# code, not XAML?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

Here is my code that does not work:

```
TheTextBox.InputScope = new InputScope();
TheTextBox.InputScope.Names.Add( 
    new InputScopeName( InputScopeNameValue.Number ) );
```

No special keyboard shows up when I tap on the TextBox. I just get the standard keyboard.

I would like to get this to work but Windows 8 apparently doesn't support this. I have searched for answers to this , but only found solutions that say to change the XAML. That is not a solution for me because I dislike having a bunch of UserControls just to have a variety of input scopes.

I have added this code to the Loaded event handler for the text control. It still didn't work there, as one internet answer suggested.

I tried using "Number" and "TelephoneNumber" and neither worked in code.

I am using Visual Studio 2012 and a Windows Store C# app project.

Thanks.

Dave

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reorder it:

```
var inputScope = new InputScope();
inputScope.Names.Add(new InputScopeName( InputScopeNameValue.Number ) );
TheTextBox.InputScope = inputScope;
```

Apparently, once you set the `InputScope` property, it doesn't watch/observe any changes that happen to the list of `Names`. So, in your code, it was always empty. I've changed it to create the scope, `Add` to it, and then set it when done.

It works in my tests.